# I'm making a bot with discord.py Rewrite and there is an error with the checks that keeps coming back

Tags: python, coroutine, discord.py

I'm making a command that robs money (The bot's currency) from other users. I get an error saying

```
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable
```

When I type !rob 1000 [user], it shows the error. When I remove the check:

```
def iDevs(ctx):
    return ctx.author.id == [id]

@commands.check(iDevs)
```

The error goes away.

Here is the code. I'm sorry if it's long.

```
def iDevs(ctx):
    return ctx.author.id == 710146098983075843


#Command
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.check(iDevs)
async def rob(ctx, amount: int, other: discord.Member):
    primary_id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    other_id = str(other.id)
    if primary_id not in amounts:
        await ctx.send("You do not have an account.")
    elif other_id not in amounts:
        await ctx.send("The person you're trying to give money to does not have an account.")
    elif amounts[primary_id] < amount:
        await ctx.send("You cannot afford this transaction.")
    elif amount < 1:
        author = ctx.message.author

        larger = discord.Embed(
            colour = discord.Colour.blue()
        )

        larger.set_author(name=f'Amount must be 1 or larger.', icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/723566996817575948/723932425369026560/comrade.png')
        larger.add_field(name='Sorry!', value='\u200b', inline=False)

        await ctx.send(embed=larger)

    else:
        amounts[primary_id] += amount
        amounts[other_id] -= amount

        author = ctx.message.author

        rob = discord.Embed(
            colour = discord.Colour.blue()
        )

        rob.set_author(name='Transaction complete.', icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/723566996817575948/723932425369026560/comrade.png', url='https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=723929187316138035&permissions=8&scope=bot')
        rob.add_field(name=f'You stole {amount} money from {other}!', value='\u200b', inline=False)
        rob.set_thumbnail(url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/723566996817575948/723932425369026560/comrade.png')

        await ctx.send(embed=rob)
```

If you know an answer, please help.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the error comes up? Is it just when you remove the check or is it a certain way you run the command?

Comment: When I have the `@commands.check(infdevs)`, it shows the error. When I remove it, the error goes away.

Comment: Could you post the full traceback? What version of `discord.py` are you using?